# Importing GIT project into eclipse mangles package names

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm trying to import a GIT repository into my eclipse (luna, 4.4).
The imported packages have "src" prefixed to the correct package name.
E.g. instead of com.myproject.test I see src.com.myproject.test.

I'm a GIT newbie. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .classpath file was not committed into the repository, so Eclipse does not correctly know where the root of your sources are. Bring up the project's Properties Dialog (use the context menu or the main menubar's Project menu) and go to the `Java Build Path` page. On its `Source` tab, you can remove the project folder itself and set `src` as the `Source Folder` to use (not that you're limited to just one in the future).

[image: Java Build Path page]